# Test $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n\ln(n)}{n}$ for convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n\ln(n)}{n}$

The first thing I think to do is the alternating series test, but $\frac{\ln(n)}{n}$ is not a monotonically decreasing sequence. For example, the derivative of this quantity is $\frac{1}{n^2}(1-\ln(n))$, and this quantity is not negative for all $n\geq1$.

Next I move on to comparison tests. I see that $\frac{\ln(n)}{n} = \ln(n^{1/n})$. I also note that $\ln(n^{1/n}) < n^{1/n}$. None of this ends up helping.

I tried the ratio test as well but couldn't prove that $|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}| \geq 1$ as I suspect the series diverges.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Note that $\frac{1}{n^2}(1-\ln(n))<0\ $ for all $n \geqslant{3}$ and rejection of a finite number of terms does not affect the convergence

Answer (score 3):

Put $$f(t) = {\log(t)\over t}.$$
Then 
$$f'(t) = {t(1/t) - \log(t) \over t^2}= {1-\log(t)\over t^2}$$
This is decreasing for $t \ge 3$. Therefore the alternating series test will work for you.

Comment: Could you please expand a bit more on that answer?